# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax, can't import DB to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I have a localhost with apache server, mysql and php 
I tried to import .SQL to existed DB called MAFS, mySQL **version is 3.5** 
but it showed me this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
USE [MAFS]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTransportations](
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[TransId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Persons] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
//** the rest of the sql query **//
```

I can't figure out what my error is

Comment: because the statements were generated from `SQL Server`. you need to manually remove some stuffs before executing it on mysql.

Comment: is there any convertor or something could do that!

Comment: Maybe, but you shouldn't want that. If such a converter interprets your statement in another way than you'd interpret it, you'd be adding stuff to your database of which you don't know that it doesn't do what you want. Other than that, you don't know what you're adding. What would you do if you'd have to fix a bug, which happens to reside in this statement? You're way better off rewriting it in a MySQL compliant syntax.